# Swift Charts: Labels on Y-Axis is missing after zooming

Tags: ios, charts, linechart, ios-charts

I'm very new dealing charts in swift. Using `LineChartView` to plot my data on graph. On zooming,values on Y-axis min and max change accordingly based on values of viewport min and max. For that implemented the following delegate.

```
func chartScaled(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, scaleX: CGFloat, scaleY: CGFloat) {       
    self.mapView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = axisY[Int(self.mapView.highestVisibleX)]
    self.mapView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = axisY[Int(self.mapView.lowestVisibleX)]
}
```

Sometimes working fine, but after scaling the graph,the labels are not visible and graph is not scaling to normal position also.
[image: Misisng labels]

Snippet for `leftaxis`

```
self.mapView!.leftAxis.enabled = true
self.mapView!.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
self.mapView!.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.5
self.mapView!.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.4
self.mapView.leftAxis.granularity = 5.0
self.mapView.leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true
```

Please help me out where am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you are changing Maximum & minium in scale method ?

Comment: @CodeChanger Thats the functionality I have to implement. Y-Axis labels should contain min and max of visible viewport.